# SSD on Macbook mid2010

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I've just installed a new SSD on my old Macbook mid2010 in the CD unit, so i took away the cds, to upgrade to this new extra Hard drive. 
On the other side, I replace my old HD for a new 1tb HD so I can save my Multimedia data on it, without taking place of the space the SSD has for opperational use. 
It works great, because I start over with the finder and it runs great booting from the SSD. But I still have the question if it would be better, if I plugged the SSD in the old HD slot. The question came to after i did the whole upgrade.

Should be better the other way around?

Comment: Check in About this Mac, .....SATA for the connection speed, that should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

As *johnfinn68* answered in this [Apple Discussions post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4015656):

> To determine [the bus speed of HDD and SuperDrive slots], go to the apple icon, about this mac, more info,select Serial ATA, then look at the (on mine) Nvidia AHCI and see the Link Speed and Negotiated Link speed.  The default one shown is the HDD, you need to click on the other AHCI channel to see the optical drive specs.  This will help you determine where to put the SSD.

Comment: Great answer?, you just said the same as I did.